# Is it possible to apply pre/post tags by using elasticsearch-dsl (python)?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have started playing with kibana and elasticsearch,

and have found out there is a simple possibility to wrap the matching words 
**with different tags** such as:

```
GET /product/default/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match":{
            "name":"Bingo"
    },
    "highlight":{
        "pre_tags" : ["<strong>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</strong>"],
        "fields":{
            "name":{}
        }
    }
}
```

i would like to replace the default tags **em** for Bingo with **strong** (i prefer not replacing it with the str.replace() function), 
How can i accomplish this with **elasticsearch-dsl** (version 7.0.0)? is it supported?

Comment: Can anyone assist me with this??

Comment: Eventually, I found the solution:
s = s.highlight(field_name, pre_tags=["<strong>"], post_tags=["</strong>"])